# DataGridView adding new row when it should not, strange behavior

Tags: c#, datagridview

in c # I have an object of type Human with properties Id, Name, Address ... based on that I created a list of Humans and did
humansBindingSource.DataSource = Humans
after that I connected it to DataGridView
dgvHumans.DataSource = humansBindingSource

All this works as it should, but something strange happens when I click to add a new row at bottom in a situation when I type something in DataGridView in the Name field and then delete all entered letters because I have changed my mind and I will not add a new one and click to the line above that row remains Id = 0, Name = null, Address = null and also this add new object to list... it should not be like that, but it should cancel that entry as in the case when the row for a new entry is clicked and then any row above is clicked. I hope that I managed to explain what the problem is.

Comment: I think the escape key will cancel the add.

Comment: Yes it will, but suppose the user of the program doesn't know it about esc and just deletes what he wrote, there is still a problem with a new object that shouldn't have been made, there is still a bug.

Comment: I could insert a field check after typing so if it's null for BindingSource to call the CancelEdit method and so I don't allow a blank row entry but I'm wondering if it's possible that DataGridView is with that bug or I'm missing something

Comment: That is the convention. Any other behavior would seem unexpected in my opinion. Also, blank data can be valid data. How would the grid know if it was a valid row or if you want it deleted? Anyway, the grid has many event hooks you can use for your custom logic.

Comment: You need to clarify what a valid row would look like. DO ALL the cells need data or just certain cells. In this case with a `Human` object, I would guess that the `Human` MUST have an ID and a Name, however the address may be empty. Can you clarify “which” cells can not be empty? It appears that what you are looking for is the grids `RowValidating` event. That event fires when a user tries to “leave” the current row being edited. In addition, what do you want to happen if the user clears all the data of an “existing” row? Would you “remove” that row from the list?

Comment: From that point of view, if it makes sense for the field to be blank, then DataGridView's behavior is fine, especially since it is such a convention. Thank you all for your help, I solved what bothered me, it's not up to me, but it's the way dgv behavior and I will use the validation of the row or cell to make the entry as it should be. Thanks again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.